# Every bounded subset is finite implies discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If, in a metric space, every bounded subset is finite, does that imply the topology is the discrete topology? If not, what other conditions are needed to ensure this?

I encountered the problem while reading a proof of the fact that $log (O_K^×) $for a number field $K$ is a discrete subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $x$ be any element and consider $B(x,1)$. This ball is bounded, so it is finite. Let $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ be the points in this set excluding $x$ itself. Let $r$ be the minimum of $d(x,x_i), 1\leq i \leq n$. Then $B(x,r)=\{x\}$. this proves that every singleton set is open. Hence the topoogy is discrete.

Comment: What are the conditions on the space for this statement to be true? I am guessing Hausdorff? Since one can trivially come up with examples of finite topological spaces where all bounded subsets (indeed all subsets) are finite but do not have the discrete topology.

Comment: @Math1000 How do you define bounded sets in a topological space?

Comment: Hmm, that is a good point, there would have to be a distance for the concept of boundedness to apply. Never mind then.